# ordenar una lista según valor numérico y abecedario

Tags: python

Quiero ordenar una lista con letras, para ello he creado dos listas una para las letras y otra con un valor numérico.

Queda algo parecido a esto,

```
['a','f','e','z','b','j']
[ 5 , 3 , 3 , 2 , 2 , 1 ]
```

'a' se relaciona con 5, 'f' con 3, 'e' con 3. Es decir, que su nexo es el índice.
Quiero ordenarlas numéricamente pero en caso de que dos tengan el mismo valor, tenga preferencia el orden alfabético. Es decir, el resultado sería,

```
['a','e','f','b','z','j']
[ 5 , 3 , 3 , 2 , 2 , 1 ]
```

He estado mirando y veo que existe `sort()` pero no se como plantearlo ya que si aplico esto, se me ordenan todos y yo solo querría ordenar aquellos en los que haya coincidencia numérica.

Se que no estoy añadiendo código pero es que realmente no hago código para corregir porque el problema es que no se cómo plantearme la solución. Lo intento recorrer con bucles y condicionales pero me quedan cosas enormes y encima con errores, cuando estoy seguro que esto debe ser bastante sencillo y rápido. ¿Cómo lo puedo plantear?¿Hay alguna función que desconozca que ayude?

Como nota, añadir que la lista de letras (y en consecuencia la numérica) no tiene un tamaño fijo.

¡Salud y gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La solución que te propongo usa varios trucos de programación funcional.

La función `zip()` puede ser de ayuda aquí. Esta función recibe N listas como parámetros y te devuelve un iterable en el que, cada vez que iteras, te da como resultado una tupla con N elementos, el primero sacado de la primera list, el segundo de la segunda, etc.

Así, si lo usamos sobre tus dos listas, usando primero la de los números, tenemos:

```
letras = ['a','f','e','z','b','j']
numeros = [ 5 , 3 , 3 , 2 , 2 , 1 ]
parejas = zip(numeros, letras)
print(list(parejas))
```

```
[(5, 'a'), (3, 'f'), (3, 'e'), (2, 'z'), (2, 'b'), (1, 'j')]
```

La función `sorted()` sirve para ordenar listas. Si le pasamos la lista anterior, ordenará las tuplas por el método de comparar primero su primer elemento, y si son iguales comparar el segundo. Es decir, nos dejará estas tuplas justo en el orden que querías:

```
parejas = zip(numeros, letras)
ordenado = sorted(parejas)
print(ordenado)
```

```
[(1, 'j'), (2, 'b'), (2, 'z'), (3, 'e'), (3, 'f'), (5, 'a')]
```

Sólo queda volver a separar las tuplas otra vez en dos listas. Aunque esto podría hacerse con un bucle, voy a usar de nuevo programación funcioal, utilizando `zip()` de una forma un tanto críptica:

```
numeros, letras = zip(*ordenado)
print(numeros)
print(letras)
```

```
(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 5)
('j', 'b', 'z', 'e', 'f', 'a')
```

El asterisco delante de `*ordenado` es el operador de "desempaquetado". Lo que hace es convertir la lista `ordenado` en una serie de argumentos que le pasa a `zip()` como parámetros. En este caso es como si hubiésemos llamado así a `zip()`:

```
zip((1, 'j'), (2, 'b'), (2, 'z'), (3, 'e'), (3, 'f'), (5, 'a'))
```

es decir, pasándole 6 parámetros, cada uno de ellos una tupla con 2 elementos. `zip()` hará lo mismo que antes y nos devolverá un iterador en el que cada vez que itere me saldrá una tupla, con tantos elementos como parámetros le pasé a `zip()`, cogiendo en la primera iteración el primer elemento de cada tupla, en la segunda iteración el segundo elemento,etc. Por tanto separando las listas otra vez.

Todo lo anterior puede dejarse en una sola (y críptica) línea:

```
letras = ['a','f','e','z','b','j']
numeros = [ 5 , 3 , 3 , 2 , 2 , 1 ]
numeros, letras = zip(*sorted(zip(numeros, letras)))
```

**Postdata**

La solución anterior tiene el efecto secundario de que el resultado en `numeros` y `letras` es ahora una tupla, en vez de una lista. Naturalmente puedes hacer al final:

```
numeros = list(numeros)
letras = list(letras)
```

pero para los fanáticos de la programación funcional y de los *one-liners*, también se puede hacer esto:

```
numeros, letras = map(list, zip(*sorted(zip(numeros, letras))))
```